# What's wrong with my "parallel to serial" verilog code

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to design a parallel to serial converter. But my final waveform look like this:[image]

Here is my code, thanks in advance.

```
module parallel2serial#(parameter size=4)(pin, clk, load, rst, sout, finish);
  input [size-1 :0] pin;
  input clk, rst, load;
  output reg finish;
  output sout;
  reg [2:0]count;
  reg [size-1 :0] data;
  reg dout;

  always@(posedge clk)begin
    if(!rst)begin dout<=0; end
    else if(!load)begin
        data<=data>>1;
        dout<=data[size-1];
    end
    else data<=pin;
  end

  always@(posedge clk)begin
    if(!rst)begin count<=0; finish<=0;end
    else begin
      if(count==2'b11) begin count<=0; finish<=1;end
      else begin count<=count+1; finish<=0;end
    end

  end
  assign sout=dout;
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's at least one mistake. You're shifting data towards the least significant bit (to the right), while taking the output from the most significant bit. You should either output lsb instead of msb, or change the direction of register shifting.